# Why is this blog featured as community bulletin?

Tags: support, community-blog

Today, I can see [this blog](http://stackexchange.com/blogs/2014/02/the-blessed-land-part-2-bani-israeel/?cb=1) link featured in the community bulletin. While visiting the blog, it showed the page not found error. Is this restriction is for specific users or for all?

Why is this broken link featured in the community bulletin and what is that blog all about?

Answer (score 4):

All blog articles posted to the Islam Stack Exchange Blog, the official community blog run by this community, get featured in the Community Bulletin for a few days after they are published. Usually, the link works and for example on my end it still works. [There have been recent issues with reaching the blog for some users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221876/diy-blogoverflow-com-is-redirecting-to-stackexchange-com-blogs), which should be resolved by now but there may be some lingering issues. If the problems persist for, say, to tomorrow, then I'll get some extra investigation going on.

As for the blog itself, to quote the About page in case you still can't access it:

> **This is the official blog run by the Islam Stack Exchange community.**
>
> This blog will deal with a wide range of subjects, from Da’wah, to History, to the Islamic sciences, as well as things about the site like updates, current issues etc.  The subjects are not limited to the subjects previously mentioned.  We pray that this blog will help make the site more beneficial for those who visit, as well as benefit those around the internet.
>
> Any member of the community can contribute. If you have a suggestion for a post here, comment on [meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/). Regular contributors are given an account on the blog, where they can submit posts to be reviewed. We have also selected Editors who can review and publish posts.

Comment: still I can't access that page.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll get someone to look into this.